# Problem with Android Studio, SearchView prevents me from starting the app

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm relying on videos to make a social network on Android, I don't know why that error appears to me, if anyone knows how to solve it I would greatly appreciate it. The videos are from the Atif Pervaiz channel, the specific video is the Firebase Social Media App - 18 Show and Search Posts

[image: screenshot]

**In Activity HomeFragment**`enter code here`

```js
package com.example.whatsappinacap;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.whatsappinacap.adapters.AdapterPosts;
import com.example.whatsappinacap.models.ModelPost;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<ModelPost> postList;
    AdapterPosts adapterPosts;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.postRecyclerview);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        postList=new ArrayList<>();

        loadPosts();

        return view;

    }

    private void loadPosts() {
        DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                postList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    ModelPost modelPost=ds.getValue(ModelPost.class);
                    postList.add(modelPost);
                    adapterPosts=new AdapterPosts(getActivity(), postList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterPosts);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void searchPosts(final String searchQuery){
        DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                postList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    ModelPost modelPost=ds.getValue(ModelPost.class);
                    if (modelPost.getpTitle().toLowerCase().contains(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) ||
                            modelPost.getpDescr().toLowerCase().contains(searchQuery.toLowerCase())){
                        postList.add(modelPost);
                    }

                    adapterPosts=new AdapterPosts(getActivity(), postList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterPosts);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void checkUserStatus(){
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null){

        }
        else {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s)){
                    searchPosts(s);
                }
                else {
                    loadPosts();
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s)){
                    searchPosts(s);
                }
                else {
                    loadPosts();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_logout){
            firebaseAuth.signOut();
            checkUserStatus();
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_add_post){
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), AddPostActivity.class));
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  

enter code here

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
And the xml
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/postRecyclerview"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

```
}
```

**strong text**

Comment: Please state what exactly you are trying to do and what is the problem you are facing. The screenshot is not readable (for me at least)

Comment: What I am trying to do there is that the app can search for a particular post, I also rely on videos on this, the channel is Atif Pervaiz and the video in particular is the 18 Show and Search Posts

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your very limited explanation. The only thing I could suggest for you to fix this problem would be by changing your import statement (located on top of your file)

from

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
```

into

```
import android.widget.SearchView
```

After you put more detailed explanation about you problem.
I'll update my answer in case this is not what you're looking for.

Comment: If I have that importation, and I am still new to this page, I am editing my problem so that you can help me, thanks for answering fast

Comment: Did you to change your import statement, like what I stated above? Is it still give you the same error

Comment: it was the import, that was the problem, thanks for the help